# Transfer Value From Solidity Contract To Ganache Account With Web3.js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

I'm trying to transfer the balance of my contract to a ganache account from the UI.

This is my solidity function which works fine in remix:

```
function tapGreen(address _receiverAddress) onlySwiper payable public {
    _receiverAddress.transfer(this.balance); 
}
```

Here is what I have in my js file

```
swipeRight: function() {
    console.log(addressInput.value);
    App.contracts.HackathonDapp.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        return instance.tapGreen(addressInput.value).sendTransaction ({
            from: web3.eth.accounts[1],
            value: web3.eth.getBalance(contracts.address) 
});
```

The `addressInput.value` comes from an HTML form.

When I tap the green button and try to send the ether to the other account I get this error in my metamask [image]

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web3 API is sometimes confusing because there are significant changes between 0.20.x and 1.0. It's hard to tell which version you're using.

If you're on 0.20.x, the call should be

```
instance.tapGreen.sendTransaction(addressInput.value, {
    from: fromAccount,
    value: valueInWei 
});
```

If you're using 1.0, the call would be

```
instance.methods.tapGreen(addressInput.value).send({
    from: fromAccount,
    value: valueInWei 
});
```

Note that I purposely changed the values in the transaction object to variables since the synchronous versions of `web3.eth.account` and `web3.eth.getBalance` are not available in 1.0 and it's best practice to use the async versions (using callbacks) in 0.20.x as well.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

`swipeRight: function() {
        console.log(addressInput.value);
        var swipeRight = web3.eth.getBalance(contracts.address);
        var accountOne = web3.eth.accounts[1]; 
        App.contracts.DatingHackathon.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            return instance.tapGreen.sendTransaction(addressInput.value, {
                 from: accountOne,
                 value: swipeRight
            });
}`

Still getting an error which says: 

"Uncaught ReferenceError: contracts is not defined"

Comment: I am using web3 version 0.2^

Comment: I don't know what `contracts` is. I'm guessing you mean to use `instance.address` there. Also, like I mentioned in my answer, I recommend using `web3.eth.getBalance(contracts.address, (e, r) => if (!e) balance = r)`

Comment: Sorry about that! 
Here is where I assign the value to my contracts variable

    `initContract: function() {
        $.getJSON('HackathonDapp.json', function (artifactsData) {
            App.contracts.HackathonDapp = TruffleContract(artifactsData);
            App.contracts.HackathonDapp.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
            console.log("initialized Election contract");
        })
        return App.bindEvents();
    },`